# display button on the same line of the input text

Tags: html, css

I'm using datepicker from [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) in this way:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Birth Date:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <input type="text"
                class="form-control"
                datepicker-popup="MMMM dd, yyyy"
                ng-model="panels.patient.birthDate"
                is-open="pdfc.opened"
                ng-required="true"
                close-text="Close" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="pdfc.open()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The button is displayed in a new line as if there was a `<br />`. Is there a way to display the button in the same line of the `<input />` like it happens in [these examples](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker)?

Comment: Could you try and put together a representative fiddle - it ends up on the same line for me.

Comment: Give a class of `form-inline` to your form or container `div`. Ref: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline

Comment: Try one of these or all together: 1) Resize the input, 2) set `display:inline;` on both, 3) add a `float:left;` on both with a clearfix after the button.

Comment: As Luis P. A. notices, it works fine with firefox but not with chrome :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `input-group` instead `form-group`

**HTML**

```
    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Birth Date:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text"
                class="form-control"
                datepicker-popup="MMMM dd, yyyy"
                ng-model="panels.patient.birthDate"
                is-open="pdfc.opened"
                ng-required="true"
                close-text="Close" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="pdfc.open()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
      </span>
    </div>
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/1f050smo/13/)**

Comment: Luis I need the input and the button in the same level. In your demo they are not.

Comment: ?? They are in the same level (on the same line - horizontal)..ahhh its working on firefox..but it semmes is not working on chrome

Comment: I think the problem is with the grid (markup places)..i made some changes on the markup (grid)...try again please

Answer (score 0):

Just set the display of the input to 'inline-block'

CSS:

```
.form-group input {
  display: inline-block;
}
```